# Are there any platform-specific limitations to `std::this_thread::sleep_for()`?

Tags: c++, c++11, timer

Are there any known portability issues to consider when using `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` for milliseconds and upward?

In a project I'm working on, I hope to replace a bouquet of platform-specific implementations all designed to yield for a specified number of milliseconds, give or take, using anything from Microsoft's `Sleep()` to `naonsleep()` to `usleep`, depending on what is available on a particular platform. Some of these come with notable limitations, such as not supporting delays of 1000 ms or more on certain platforms.

Does `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` suffer from such quirks, too?

Comment: Although it doesn't appear like the limits of `sleep_for()` are explicitly specified, I would be surprised if intervals of a few seconds would be problematic. Given the semantics of `sleep_for()`, if a particular implementation has some internal limits, it seems almost a no-brainer for the C++ library to handle the internal limits by itself, simply by sleeping repeatedly, for the maximum supported interval, until the requested delay has been reached.

Comment: "I'd be surprised if..." doesn't sound reassuring to me -- platform-specific implementations have too often surprised me in any number of ways ;)

Answer (score 2):

Maximum sleep duration: `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` does not have any problem here. You can sleep as long as you like.

Precision: `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` has the same problems which all the other sleep functions you mention also have: **Probably not! See update below!**

Any sleep function will suffer the `quirk` that it is entirely up to the scheduler in your operating system when your task is actually resumed. Your sleep times will generally alias somewhat around the minimum time slice of your preemptive multitasking scheduler.

To make things worse, this time slice is not always constant on all OSes.

On Linux you usually have 10 ms time slices and sleeping less than 10 ms *may* result in sleeping 0 ms. Sleeping for 10 ms may result in sleeping for *about* 10 ms, or longer, potentially but not necessarily aligned to a time slice size.

In short: You cannot rely at all on any of the sleep functions, including `std::this_thread::sleep_for()`.

There is another class of sleep functions which does busy waiting. This is usually used when waiting for times which are significantly shorter than a scheduling time slice (say 2 us). But of course even this may be very inaccurate since your task may get preempted even on an almost idle system, and then you can add 10 ms to your 2 us sleep time.

On a multitasking operating system you have no chance: You cannot sleep precisely. The sleep functions have errors, and they even have systematic errors, so sleeping 100 times 10 ms may sleep anything between 0 and 2 seconds in practice.

If you have long-term time requirements the only chance you have is to constantly query the wall-clock time.

**Update: Benchmarks on Linux and macOS:**

At least on Linux and macOS `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` are pretty precise for millisecond resolution and so *not* suffer from all the artifacts I described above:

Linux benchmark: Each sleep is called repeatedly for a total duration of one second and the real average sleep time is given (e.g. averaging over 200 calls to sleep(5 ms)):

```
std::this_thread::sleep( 1 ms) slept really 1.13915 ms
std::this_thread::sleep( 2 ms) slept really 2.15215 ms
std::this_thread::sleep( 3 ms) slept really 3.14976 ms
std::this_thread::sleep( 4 ms) slept really 4.15059 ms
std::this_thread::sleep( 5 ms) slept really 5.15062 ms
std::this_thread::sleep( 6 ms) slept really 6.15008 ms
std::this_thread::sleep( 7 ms) slept really 7.14988 ms
std::this_thread::sleep( 8 ms) slept really 8.14979 ms
std::this_thread::sleep( 9 ms) slept really 9.15044 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(10 ms) slept really 10.1504 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(11 ms) slept really 11.1511 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(12 ms) slept really 12.1505 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(13 ms) slept really 13.1504 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(14 ms) slept really 14.1501 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(15 ms) slept really 15.1503 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(16 ms) slept really 16.1499 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(17 ms) slept really 17.1505 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(18 ms) slept really 18.1505 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(19 ms) slept really 19.1504 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(20 ms) slept really 20.1505 ms
```

Same for macOS:

```
std::this_thread::sleep( 1 ms) slept really 1.27451 ms
std::this_thread::sleep( 2 ms) slept really 2.45646 ms
std::this_thread::sleep( 3 ms) slept really 3.61991 ms
std::this_thread::sleep( 4 ms) slept really 4.77443 ms
std::this_thread::sleep( 5 ms) slept really 5.7994 ms
std::this_thread::sleep( 6 ms) slept really 7.03769 ms
std::this_thread::sleep( 7 ms) slept really 8.13089 ms
std::this_thread::sleep( 8 ms) slept really 9.13276 ms
std::this_thread::sleep( 9 ms) slept really 10.441 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(10 ms) slept really 11.5895 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(11 ms) slept really 12.77 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(12 ms) slept really 13.8207 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(13 ms) slept really 14.9366 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(14 ms) slept really 16.4569 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(15 ms) slept really 17.27 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(16 ms) slept really 18.2013 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(17 ms) slept really 19.6347 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(18 ms) slept really 20.7785 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(19 ms) slept really 22.9571 ms
std::this_thread::sleep(20 ms) slept really 23.2532 ms
```

Both runs are on an idle system. Interesting: On Linux the numbers get more precise on a loaded system (yes in a screen session). Scheduler artifacts! But small ones! :-)

This is for `usleep()` on Linux: Also pretty precise. I no longer believe what I wrote above:

```
usleep( 1 ms) slept really  1.148 ms
usleep( 2 ms) slept really  2.152 ms
usleep( 3 ms) slept really  3.151 ms
usleep( 4 ms) slept really  4.151 ms
usleep( 5 ms) slept really  5.149 ms
usleep( 6 ms) slept really  6.149 ms
usleep( 7 ms) slept really  7.149 ms
usleep( 8 ms) slept really  8.150 ms
usleep( 9 ms) slept really  9.150 ms
usleep(10 ms) slept really 10.150 ms
usleep(11 ms) slept really 11.149 ms
usleep(12 ms) slept really 12.149 ms
usleep(13 ms) slept really 13.150 ms
usleep(14 ms) slept really 14.150 ms
usleep(15 ms) slept really 15.149 ms
usleep(16 ms) slept really 16.149 ms
usleep(17 ms) slept really 17.150 ms
usleep(18 ms) slept really 18.150 ms
usleep(19 ms) slept really 19.149 ms
usleep(20 ms) slept really 20.149 ms
```

Comment: This is not what was asked.

Comment: This is informative, but doesn't appear to be what the OP is asking about. The minimum time slice is rarely an issue, because it's typically low, although on Windows a program may alter it, which can affect other programs, but `sleep_for` doesn't suffer any worse than `Sleep` or `usleep` or anything. Only things like `condition_variable` work around those issues I think, since you're specifically telling the OS what you're waiting for.

Comment: @Sam: Says the one who 1. answers in a comment and 2. does not answer the question either and 3. gives a wrong answer (by indicating that sleep_for() may suffer an implementation dependent upper limit in the order of seconds, which is plain wrong). SCNR. ;-)

Comment: @Sam maybe leave it up to the OP of the question to decide whether the information is relevant for them ;).

Comment: This is indeed not _exactly_ what I was asking about, and I was aware that multitasking would affect the delay _somewhat_, but it is still informative. For instance, I didn't expect the granularity to be as high as 10ms.

Comment: @Sam this looks like a reasonable and informative answer to me.  Keep in mind that 'what was asked" includes the title of the question as well as the body of the question.

Comment: @JohannesOvermann You're saying "On Linux [...] sleeping less than 10 ms may result in sleeping 0 ms" - can I still expect to sleep for roundabout 10 ms _on average_? - Also, isn't sleeping for _less_ than the specified duration technically in violation to the standard? (Not that it would help me much.)

Comment: @Christoph: You should not expect it to sleep 10 ms on average. The algorithms are neither smart nor fair. I have seen Linux systems which consistently sleep 0 ms (but that was before C++11) for a sleep interval < 10 ms. And yes, I also find it a violation of the standard. And yes, it does not help us. The only thing you can rely on is to query the time after you come back from sleep and adapt accordingly. Thats the pragmatic and conservative and portable approach. I haven't checked the very recent C++11 implementations I must admit. The may do better.

Comment: "I have seen Linux systems which consistently sleep 0 ms (but that was before C++11) for a sleep interval < 10 ms" - that can't have been `std::this_thread_sleep_for()` then, right?

Comment: @Christoph: Correct. I should just try it now. I'm curious!

Comment: @Christoph: I ran some benchmarks, and indeed I was wrong and at least for Linux and macOS sleep_for() is pretty precise, around +/-1 ms which is quite good I would say.

Answer (score 0):

sleep_for supports longer delays, as it accepts any valid duration value. However, it does have limitations:

`sleep_for` generally uses `std::chrono::steady_clock`, and is thus subject to the limitations of that clock. The standard requires that clock to monotonically advance. But the resolution may vary from implementation to implementation.

Also,

> This function may block for longer than sleep_duration due to scheduling or resource contention delays. [sleep_for (cpp reference)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

So `sleep_for` may sleep for longer than specified.